# AngularJS: translate and multiple ng-bind-html values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translate

In my app I try to concat two strings: email and some text.

But I have a trouble, I need text part translateable *"on the fly"* so I wrote:

```
$scope.textUnsubscribe = 'SUCESSFULL_UNSUBSCRIBE';
```

in view:

```
<h4 ng-bind-html="textUnsubscribe | translate"></h4>
```

sure I can do (email + text):

```
<h4 ng-bind-html="userEmail"></h4>
<h4 ng-bind-html="textUnsubscribe | translate"></h4>
```

but then I have style bug...

Can I somehow put into one `ng-bind-html` two scope variables? one is "static" and second is translateable?

like:

```
<h4 ng-bind-html="userEmail, (textUnsubscribe | translate)"></h4>
```

Comment: @Pierre-AlexandreMoller forget about css...
is it real to concat two vars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's only simple string like email. You don't need `ng-bind-html`, `ng-bind` will be enough. Adding `-html` make `ng-bind` less safer. Anyway `ng-bind` can be used multiple times. If you have a "style bug" with it, it comes from your HTML (you have multiple `h4`).

Anyway, you can do it on a simple `ng-bind` like this :

```
<h4 ng-bind="userEmail +' '+ (textUnsubscribe | translate)"></h4>
```